# Matlab Computation and Applied Modelling

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, computational-mathematics

Worked out so far;
four equations from Newtons law of cooling: T=temp T*= environmental temp. S= salinity S*= environmental Salinity H= salt flux

dT1/dt = k(T1-T1*)
dT2/dt = -k(T2-T2*)
dS1/dt = k(S1-S1*) - H
dS2/dt = -k(S2-S2*) + H

I figured these could be reduced further for example:
dT2/dt - dT1/dt = d(delta T)/t = -k(T2-T2*) - k(T1-T1*)

my question is in order to solve the ode : do I have to solve for dT1/dt and dT2/dt separately: giving T1-T1* = Ce^kt for example and substitute the solutions to find d(delta T)/t so that d(delta T)/t = -k(ce^kt)...
or do I have to solve d(delta T)/t as it is.

Also computing it in matlab using Syms: but not too sure how.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are assuming the salt flux to be a constant? In many cases it is assume to depend on water flux and ultimately on pressure. If it is not constant, you are missing an equation to close the system.

Comment: @PierreCarre we have been told to assume H=0 for the time being for simplicity

Comment: In that case all your equations are independent and can be solved in an exact manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your model

$$
\cases{
\frac{dT_1}{dt}=k(T_1-T_1^*)\\
\frac{dT_2}{dt}=-k(T_2-T_2^*)\\
\frac{dS_1}{dt}=k(S_1-S_1^*)-H\\
\frac{dS_2}{dt}=-k(S_2-S_2^*)+H\\
}
$$

we can conclude that all the variables involved $T_1,T_2,S_1,S_2$ are each other independent. They depend only on $t$ which the independent variable hence we can solve independently for each $T_1,T_2,S_1,S_2$

Comment: in that case would the following workings be along the correct path:

dT1/dt = k(T1-T1*)    giving

T1= Ce^(kt) + T1*……..
dT2/dt = -k(T2-T2*)   giving

T2= Ce^(-kt)+ T2*
…….
delta T = T2 - T1 = Ce^(-kt) + T2* - Ce^(kt) - T1* 
now assuming that T2*=T1*
we get that delta T = T2-T1 = Ce^(-kt) - Ce^(kt)